# Returning results that are not null in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a MySQL query like so:

```
SELECT `contact_last_name` FROM `customer` WHERE `contact_last_name` IS NOT NULL
```

Basically I want to return any rows where the column `contact_last_name` has something entered in it. If it makes any difference, this column is a VARCHAR column.

But instead, it is returning every row in the database, regardless of whether that column is empty or not!

I'm not sure why this query is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` requires the column to actually be `NULL`. Not an empty string. Are you trying to check if it's empty?

```
SELECT 
    `contact_last_name` 
FROM 
    `customer` 
WHERE 
    `contact_last_name` != ''
```

Do you have white space issues?

```
SELECT 
    `contact_last_name` 
FROM 
    `customer` 
WHERE 
    TRIM(`contact_last_name`) != ''
```

Can it both be `NULL` and empty?

```
SELECT 
    `contact_last_name` 
FROM 
    `customer` 
WHERE 
    `contact_last_name` != '' 
AND 
    `contact_last_name` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: There is literally nothing in that column for all except a couple of rows. In phpMyAdmin, looking at a random row with that column empty does indeed show it as having no white spaces or anything. Your first example works well for me though, so I'll use that - thank you!

Comment: @SamG Also note that in PHPMyAdmin when changing columns there's a `NULL` checkbox. If this is enabled it allows the column to actually be `NULL` instead of an empty string. `UPDATE contact_last_name SET customer = NULL WHERE customer = ''`

Comment: Can we get away with just `!=` in the last case? `NULL` is not equal to anything.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between a varchar being an empty string and it being explicitly NULL. You could try this where clause:

```
LENGTH(contact_last_name) > 0;
```

Comment: Are you certain that `LENGTH()` function is available in **MySql**?

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` (unknown value) is different to "blank" (known, but zero-length string), so you must check for both:

```
SELECT contact_last_name
FROM customer
WHERE contact_last_name IS NOT NULL
AND contact_last_name != ''
```

With mysql, this can be shortened to:

```
SELECT contact_last_name
FROM customer
WHERE ifnull(contact_last_name, '') != ''
```

Note also the removal of the unnecessary backticks from your query - none of the column/table names you have are reserved words.